# How to proxy and encrypt all my internet traffic with Win7 and Win2008R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, proxy, encryption

I have a Windows 7 laptop and a Windows 2008 R2 server.

How can I encrypt and route all my internet request from the Win7 laptop to the Win2008R2 server? I guess the server would be called a proxy? Goal is to prevent unencrypted network snooping.

I found this article about using SSH, but I would prefer an official windows integrated solution. What's the Microsoft "way" on this?
http://lifehacker.com/237227/geek-to-live--encrypt-your-web-browsing-session-with-an-ssh-socks-proxy

I would like this to work for all internet traffic, not just browser traffic and I would like to set this up on many Win7 clients.

Carl

Answer (score 1):

MS Solution: [IPSec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732283%28WS.10%29.aspx) + [FF:TMG](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/threat-management-gateway/en/us/default.aspx)

This is not an easy or free solution. It would be easier to run a [SSHd on the Server](http://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+SSHd), especially if it's just a few people using this.

Answer (score 0):

Traffic to your *own* server? => Install OpenVPN or LogMeIn Hamachi²